# Listing all possible train routes

Tags: graphs, routing

I'm interested whether there is the standard solution to the following problem.
Some number of train routes is given:

Route1: First City -> Next City -> ... -> Last City

Route2: ...

...

We need to list all possible ways to get from one given city to the other with possible transfers but without visiting any city more than once. So, for example, if we're given

R1: A -> B -> C

R2: B -> D -> E

R3: C -> D -> A

R4: C -> E -> F

than the routes from A to E are the following:

A -> [R1] -> B -> [R2] -> E

A -> [R1] -> C -> [R4] -> E

I hope i've managed to explain properly. And thank you very much in advance for any tips.

Comment: What have you tried?  Where did you get stuck?  We expect you to make a serious effort on your own before asking.  Some hints for things you can try on your own: 1. What classic problems does this resemble, and did you investigate that relationship?  2. In the worst case, how large could the total number of routes be?  Linear? Polynomial? Exponential?  What does this imply about the running time of any algorithm for this problem?  3. Are you looking for a practical algorithm, or for the theoretical complexity of this problem?  If the former, what parameter sizes are you dealing with?

Comment: Well, i've looked through some path-search algorithms for graphs but they don't seem to be appropriate for this problem since i need not only the path but also the places where i change the train.

In fact it's the question of pure interest so unfortunately i can say nothing about classic problems and possible number of rotes. I hoped that it's a standard problem since it seems to be used in many travel web-sites.

Comment: OK, take a look at the Hamiltonian path problem.  And again, spend some time on your own thinking about #2.  You *should* be able to say something about it -- try working through some examples.  Make an effort on your own -- this site is not a replacement for serious effort on your part.

Comment: I don't think that Hamiltonian path is what i need. But i'll look at it closer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comments, I'm assuming that if the problem asked to find all paths between $A$ and $B$ on a directed graph, you'd have no problem.  So the only hurdle is how to deal with the extra route information.
Here's an outline of the most obvious approach that I can see:

1. Convert the given set of routes to an adjacency matrix. Since each edge $(A,B)$ belongs to some route $R$, store that route in the corresponding entry for $(A,B)$ in the matrix.
2. Run your algorithm to find all paths between your start and goal nodes.
3. Convert the output of your algorithm to the desired form by collapsing all consecutive edges that belong to the same route into one edge.

Answer (score 0):

This problem has a very simple solution, it is called [DFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search)! Except whenever leaving a node, you should also clean it up (unmark it) so it can be used again the next time. This means you just need to add a single line `remove discovered label from v` at line 6 in psudo code provided there to get something like this:

```
1   procedure DFS(G,v):
2       label v as discovered
3       for all edges from v to w in G.adjacentEdges(v) do
4           if vertex w is not labeled as discovered then
5               recursively call DFS(G,w)
6       remove discovered label from v
```

This routine will iterate over all the paths originating from vertex/city `v`. But to  print the path, you also have to check if `v` is the destination city, and if so print the path traveled in this iteration.